# Why does .net core create API call result in a blank database record

Tags: asp.net-core

I have created a simple .NET Core (v. 1.0.0) Web app using Entity Framework.  I added a simple model called Item, added the scaffolding for it and tested it successfully in the web app, i.e. browsed to the Create page and entered info, POST the request and a new record is added to the database as expected.

Item.cs

...

```
public class Item {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }

    public Item() { }
    public Item (string name) { Name = name; }
}
```

...

ItemsController.cs

...

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ID,Name,Price")] Item item)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(item);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(item);
    }
```

...

When I make what I believe to be the same post from Postman or Fiddler the POST succeeds and .NET Core logs suggest the model was valid yet the record added to the database contains no data, just empty fields.

http://localhost:28707/Items/Create

Content-Type: application/json

Body:

```
{ 
    "Name" : "MyTest",
    "Price" : 120.0
}
```

Log output:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request
>   starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:28707/Items/Create  43
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information:
>   Executing action method CoreApiTest.Controllers.ItemsController.Create
>   (CoreApiTest) with arguments (CoreApiTest.Models.Item) - ModelState is
>   Valid The thread 0x2f84 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommandBuilderFactory:Information:
>   Executed DbCommand (7ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (Size = 4000), @p1='?'],
>   CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30'] SET NOCOUNT ON; INSERT INTO
>   [Item] ([Name], [Price]) VALUES (@p0, @p1); SELECT [ID] FROM [Item]
>   WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [ID] = scope_identity();
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RedirectToActionResult:Information: Executing
>   RedirectResult, redirecting to /Items.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information:
>   Executed action CoreApiTest.Controllers.ItemsController.Create
>   (CoreApiTest) in 3745.0811ms

I expect I'm overlooking something obvious but can't put my finger on it.

Comment: so, it's not saved in the database..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your model passed to the controller is empty.

`[Bind("ID,Name,Price")]` is for binding html form fields to a model, i.e. when you have a submit form and use a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` mime type.

You are sending the object via ajax as serialized json. You have to use `[FromBody]` instead to tell ASP.NET Core to deserialize the model from the post body.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] Item item)
```

Comment: Got it, you're a star!  I knew I was missing something.

Comment: Feel free to accept it if your problem was solved, so the SO bot doesn't keep pushing the question up ;)